# PFQuery to find PFUser whose key matches NSString

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I first of all apologize for the most random rambling title ever.  Here is my situation.  I populate a UITableView by getting a list of all the Facebook friends a user has that also use the app.  I get this by:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // result will contain an array with your user's friends in the "data" key
            self.friendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            self.jobsTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.friendObjects.count];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.friendObjects);
            for(NSDictionary *jobsInfo in self.friendObjects) {


                FriendArray *jobby = [[FriendArray alloc] init];
                jobby.name = [jobsInfo valueForKey:@"name"];
                NSLog(@"Name%@", jobby.name);
                // jobby.name = jobsInfo[@"additional"];
                jobby.facebookid = jobsInfo[@"id"];


                [self.jobsTemp addObject:jobby];

            }
            self.jobsArray = self.jobsTemp;
            NSLog(@"ARRAY%@", self.jobsArray);//set @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *jobsArray; in the .h
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
```

Each entry in _User has a column called fbId.  What I would like to do is search all PFUsers when a row is clicked and find the PFUser that has a fbId entry that matches the id for that particular row.  What I have tried so far is:

```
FriendArray *job = self.jobsArray[indexPath.row];

    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"_User"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

    [query whereKey:job.facebookid equalTo:object[@"fbId"]];


    NSLog(@"Query%@", [query findObjects]);
```

However, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create two PFQuery objects. One to represent the first user, the second to find the friend.

The Parse API query method you are looking for is:
- (instancetype)whereKey:(NSString *)key matchesKey:(NSString *)otherKey inQuery:(PFQuery *)query

You will do something like:

```
[friendQuery whereKey:@"id" matchesKey:@"fbId" inQuery:userQuery]
```

Comment: I don't really know if I made everything clear in my question.  If so, sorry about that.  My tableView has rows from an array.  One object in the array contains the Facebook id for a user.  Does it really require two PFQuery objects when I just need the PFUser whose key matches the string I already have?